# I want to show currency symbol and price in different html tag.

Tags: magento-1.9, price

My Requirement is

[image]
To fullfill that requirement i have put this code in `app/design/frontend/<theme>/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

```
            <?php 
             $currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency( $currency_code )->getSymbol();
             $specialprice_col = number_format($_product->getSpecialPrice(),2);
             ?>
            <div class="price"><sup>
                <?php echo $currency_symbol; ?></sup><?php echo number_format($_product->getPrice(),2); ?>
             </div>
```

but when i put this code it is working perfect in simple product but in bundle product the price shows $0 instead of my setted price.
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a minimum QTY set for the global configuration, or those grouped products individually? My understanding is that it calculates the "starting at" for grouped products based on minimum qty that can be ordered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have solved by below code.

```
<?php  $groupedprice= Mage::getModel('bundle/product_price')->getTotalPrices($_product,'min',1);
       $productType = $_product->getTypeId();
?>

    <div class="price">
        <sup>
            <?php echo $currency_symbol; ?>

        </sup>
            <?php if ($productType == 'grouped') {

           echo number_format($groupedprice,2);

        } else {

             echo number_format($_product->getPrice(),2);
        }
         ?>

     </div>
```